# Como mostrar el total de un grupo de valores que están en un mismo arreglo PHP?

Tags: php

se me presento el siguiente problema: Tengo un arreglo y necesito mostrar sus valores por pantalla pero entre cada grupo de valores se tiene que mostrar una fila adicional con el total de ese grupo. Así se ve el arreglo normal:

[image: Valores del arreglo por pantalla]

Y necesito que quede de la siguiente manera (utilice excel para que se entienda mejor):

[image: Entre grupo se muestra el total del grupo]

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, pero no se si es lo mas optimo o si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo.

```
//array de ejemplo
$array = array(
    0 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 10),
    1 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 15),
    2 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 20),
    3 => array('codigo' => 312, 'valor' => 5),
    4 => array('codigo' => 312, 'valor' => 10)
    );
    
$tamanio = sizeof($array);
$total = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $tamanio; $i++){
    //Verifico que la siguiente posición del arreglo existe
    if(array_key_exists($i + 1, $array)){
        //Si la posicion actual es igual a la siguiente
        if($array[$i]['codigo'] == $array[$i + 1]['codigo']){
            //Suma los valores y muestra la fila correspondiente
            $total = $total + $array[$i]['valor'];
            echo "Codigo: " . $array[$i]['codigo'] .  " Valor: " . $array[$i]['valor'] . "\n";
        } else {
            //Caso contrario suma los valores muestra la fila correspondiente y muestra la fila de totales
            $total = $total + $array[$i]['valor'];
            echo "Codigo: " . $array[$i]['codigo'] .  " Valor: " . $array[$i]['valor'] . "\n";
            echo "Total Valor: " . $total . "\n";
        }
        //si la clave actual es diferente a la siguiente deja en cero el valor de $total
        if($array[$i]['codigo'] != $array[$i + 1]['codigo']){
            $total = 0;
        }
    } else {
        //cuando llega a la ultima posición del arreglo suma el total muestra la ultima fila y el total del ultimo grupo
        $total = $total + $array[$i]['valor'];
        echo "Codigo: " . $array[$i]['codigo'] .  " Valor: " . $array[$i]['valor'] . "\n";
        echo "Total Valor: " . $total . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías simplificar el código que hiciste de esta manera, ya que la suma siempre se hace en ambas ocasiones entonces no es necesario duplicarlas en cada caso, se pueden colocar al principio del `for` y dentro de las condiciones dejar solo los casos en que muestras los totales.

```
//array de ejemplo
$array = array(
    0 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 10),
    1 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 15),
    2 => array('codigo' => 303, 'valor' => 20),
    3 => array('codigo' => 312, 'valor' => 5),
    4 => array('codigo' => 312, 'valor' => 10)
    );
    
$tamanio = sizeof($array);
$total = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $tamanio; $i++){
    //Suma los valores y muestra la fila correspondiente
    $total += $array[$i]['valor'];
    echo "Codigo: " . $array[$i]['codigo'] .  " Valor: " . $array[$i]['valor'] . "\n";
    //Verifico que la siguiente posición del arreglo existe
    if(array_key_exists($i + 1, $array)){
        //Si la posicion actual no es igual a la siguiente muestra la fila de totales y deja en cero el valor de $total
        if($array[$i]['codigo'] != $array[$i + 1]['codigo']){
            echo "Total Valor: " . $total . "\n";
            $total = 0;
        }
    } else {
        // Cuando llega a la ultima posición del arreglo muestra el total del ultimo grupo
        echo "Total Valor: " . $total . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo es mucho mejor así. Excelente amigo, muchas gracias por su ayuda y comentario.